# How can I browse or query live MongoDB data?

Tags: mongodb

I've googled around but couldn't find a working MongoDB viewer or data browser.

An ideal (for my needs) tool would be a web based viewer with dead simple features (browsing and doing queries).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have :

- [Mongo3](http://github.com/derailed/mongo3)
- [futon4mongo](http://github.com/sbellity/futon4mongo)

Comment: Mongo3 looks like it would be an awesome tool for an admin and developer!

Comment: yes but there are too much fashion thing. More simpliest interface must be great

Comment: @NickGreen's answer contains a better, updated list: [http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) from 10gen themselves.

Answer (score 20):

See: http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/334469038/a-couple-of-nice-gui-tools-for-mongodb
Hopefully it'll be updated frequently when new tools are available!

---

**EDIT:**

Better overview: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

I just tried MongoVUE and it works like a charm!
Check it out: http://www.mongovue.com/

Comment: WARNING:  Near as I can tell from their [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/MongoVUE/111527225578623), MongoVUE is dead; moreover, they still accept orders and take your money, but never issue a license key.  It's a shame, too; it's a very promising tool.

Comment: @JimDagg MongoVue apparantly still offers a free version of the tool: http://www.mongovue.com/purchase/, it also still displayed at the mongodb UI's page. Then again, I haven't tried it in a while, so I'm not sure if it's still the best way to go:).

Answer (score 14):

MongoHub is moved to a native mac version, please check http://github.com/bububa/MongoHub-Mac.

Answer (score 11):

**[genghisapp](http://genghisapp.com/) is what you want.**

It is a web-based GUI that is clean, light-weight, straight-forward, offers keyboard shortcuts, and works awesomely. It also supports `GridFS`.

Best of all, it's a single script!

---

[image: search]

[image: json editor]

---

**To install it**

```
$ gem install genghisapp bson_ext
```

(`bson_ext` is optional but will greatly improve the performance of the gui)

---

**To run it** (this will automatically open your web browser and navigate to the app as well)

```
genghisapp
```

---

**To stop it**

```
genghisapp --kill
```

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/Imaginea/mViewer

I have tried this one and as a viewer it's awesome with tree and document views.

Comment: mViewer is really awesome. Simple, but does what I need!

Comment: That's quite nice :) And no php!

Comment: Do you know how to select by id in the query executor though? Can't figure that out!

Comment: @UpTheCreek:- The query executor is set to execute a db.<coll>.find({}) query. So just pass in a json object with _id and its value and click execute to select by id something like this :-  {
"_id": {
        "$oid": "4e4bc3d0f2c4f71b1c194234"
    }
}

Answer (score 6):

Im just testing [Rock_Mongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo)

It's a nice tool, written in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

**MogoVue** is the best option I found so far, it has great features I did not see in other viewers, plus it gives few options to look at the data, as json, tables and hierarchy, which is extremely useful.

**Avoid MongoExplorer**, it has major issues, which can cause you huge headaches. When viewing records using this tools, it may change fields which are MongoId's to plane string, it does not give any indication on this, just does it when you focus on the id field, this bug cost me lots of time and effort trying to find "what and where in my code i'm doing this silly thing"...

Comment: WARNING: Near as I can tell from their [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/MongoVUE/111527225578623), MongoVUE is dead; moreover, they still accept orders and take your money, but never issue a license key. It's a shame, too; it's a very promising tool.

Comment: MongoVue is alive and kicking

Answer (score 4):

- [RoboMongo](http://www.robomongo.org)
- [Genghis](http://genghisapp.com/)
- And entire list from here http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/

Answer (score 2):

While the built in [Http Interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) of MongoDB isn't exactly what you are asking for, but it is available and supports a REST interface to do simple queries, etc.  This is *built-in* to the mongo instance with a default of port 28017.

- Documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface

Answer (score 2):

As well as those mentioned by shingara, there's also:

- [Opricot](http://www.icmfinland.fi/oss/opricot/)
- [PHPMoAdmin](http://www.phpmoadmin.com/)
- [MongoHub](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/mongohub.html) (I've heard mixed reviews on this one, not sure if it's maintained)

Comment: I test MongoHub and it's really bad :(

Answer (score 2):

Just pushed [mongoclikker](http://github.com/semu/mongoclikker) to GitHub. It's a dead simple [MongoDB viewer written in Node](http://github.com/semu/mongoclikker).

Answer (score 2):

There a lot of UIs on official mongo site http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

Answer (score 2):

To add to the list :)

I just made a simple Mongo browser based on a hierarchical JQueryTreeview and implemented in Sinatra and Ruby.

The reason for another viewer was that I wanted something that was fast and easy (both to use and the code base), that would let me peek at what was going on my MongoDB. Also, I wanted some nice Ajax effects. and could be the base of a more complete browser.

https://github.com/tomjoro/mongo_browser

Answer (score 1):

I just released a simple web-based data viewer called [Mongs](http://www.whit537.org/mongs/). It isn't a server admin GUI, it's focused on data browsing, which sounds like what you're interested in. Mongs is implemented in Python using the Aspen web framework.

Answer (score 1):

JMongo is nice db viewer using on fedora linux

Answer (score 1):

I started work on small project: https://github.com/lucassus/mongo_browser
It's a mongodb browser based on ruby's sinatra framework.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.razorsql.com/) is the better tool for sql as well as **No-Sql viewer** and also you can query in gui mode with this tool.

Comment: Pretty impressive piece of software, although I was looking for something more simple (and free!). Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

"**[RoboMongo](http://www.robomongo.org/)**" is easy to use and cross platform, using on centos 6.2 but no option for data import/export which can be found in "**[umongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/)**" but not easy to use as RoboMongo.

Answer (score 1):

- For web: [genghis](https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis) is simple and have much more fashion interface.
  [image: genghis]
- For desktop: [robomongo](http://robomongo.org/): Shell-centric cross-platform MongoDB management tool
  [image: robomongo]

Comment: Avoid link-only answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [`MongoDB Compass`](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?filter=enterprise#compass). You can download the community edition by entering valid information.

Answer (score 0):

I using [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/), in version 0.8.3 implemented multiply inserting documents, for more details https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/173. Robomongo also have builtin mongodb-shell may be usefully for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[Forest Admin](https://www.forestadmin.com/) is an admin panel tool that supports MangoDB (using the microservice architecture). It uses a schema flattener.

Disclaimer: I work there