# MongoDB helper applications

Tags: mongodb

Are there any good applications that people use with the MongoDB database to make it easier? I'm using MongoVUE for looking at the data and querying data. Are there any other apps that I should know about? I'm thinking of using MongoDB from now on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a MongoDB viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411087/is-there-a-mongodb-viewer)

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037400/is-there-any-decent-gui-for-mongodb and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741407/query-ide-for-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [MongoDB Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) list you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Rock Monogo is an awesome web interface for querying that you should try out.

Download rockmongo-on-windows-v0.0.2.rar from http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/downloads/list, unzip the file and run rockstart.bat. Then, login as admin/admin in to the web interface.