# Grapical database builder for MongoDB (like DBForge for MySQL)

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I really like DBForge with it's ability to create database schemes with a graphical UI.

Is there a tool like that for MongoDB?

Basically I'm looking for a tool that helps creating clean MongoDB Collections and Documents.

I'm starting a very big project in a few weeks and need to design a pretty huge MongoDB Database with lots of collections. So to keep everything organized I would like to have something graphical to look at instead of just coding the entities and their properties.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411087/how-can-i-browse-or-query-live-mongodb-data

Comment: I'm not looking for a admin UI, I know that there are some very useable out there. What I look for is a graphical scheme builder. You know, create a collection, adding fields, defining type, relate to other collection. Like here (but this is only for MySQL): http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/images/database-diagram.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Mongo Explorer @ http://mongoexplorer.com/ as it has some of the options you are looking for.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any specific MongoDB 'schema' designer.  Since a collection is itself *schema-less* it's hard to imagine exactly what that would look like.  You might for example decide in your database to store `People`, `Cats` and `Cars` all in the same collection because it happens to make it easier to query across them by name.

Typically I just use a standard class-viewer or entity designer for those occasions when I do want to see a graphical view of the objects that will be persisted as documents.

Relationships are also tricky for a graphical tool - sometimes all you have is an `ObjectId`, sometimes you denormalize and have maybe a `Name` and an `ObjectId` allowing you to display a list without fetching each item and sometimes you store an entire copy of the other object embedded in the current object.

You can even come up with ways to store data in MongoDB to mimic [multiple-inheritance](http://blog.abodit.com/2011/09/dynamic-persistence-with-mongodb-look-no-classes-polymorphism-in-c/).  Since most graphical entity designers support only single inheritance you would again have issues trying to use them with MongoDB.

In summary I recommend that you model your entities using whatever entity designer you have for the language you will be using and then worry about how to map them to collections to support your query and update patterns, adjusting them as necessary to denormalize parts of the data where you need performance, or to share a common field (by interface or inheritance) where you want to be able to easily search across entity types (e.g. `string[] Tags`, or `string Name`).

Answer (score 1):

[UI / GUI Admin Tools for MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085929/ui-gui-admin-tools-for-mongodb)

This waas answered in this post.

I an using robomongo and its good.

The latest version supports 3.0 as well.

http://mongodb-tools.com/tool/robomongo/

http://robomongo.org/