# UI / GUI Admin Tools for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, user-interface, nosql

I am wondering what are some good tools for managing MongoDB from an interfaced environment. In particular, MySQL Benchmark and pgAdmin have been great for me for MySQL and PostgreSQL, respectively. Is there an "industry standard" for both MongoDB and NoSQL databases?

Comment: Please read: [What type of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) in the help center.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool like phpMyAdmin for MongoDB databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882929/is-there-a-tool-like-phpmyadmin-for-mongodb-databases)

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use http://robomongo.org/ to manage your database

Comment: Robomongo is probably the best out for Windows. If using MongoDB 3.2 do upgrade to 0.9.9-rc3 : http://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0-rc3/windows/robomongo-0.9.0-rc3-windows-x86_64-0476204.exe Previous versions have issues with MongoDB v.3.0.x onward, for example collections and documents were not shown on the Explorer View, although successfully created via shell.